# Why does saving an image with OpenCV result in a black image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

So, I want to create a 500x500 white image using python Numpy library, though I can easily do it in photoshop. The code below is valid and the image is white (because I saved the image using cv2.imsave function and later I opened it with windows photos viewer). But when I try to display it using the cv2.imshow function a black image is displayed. Why is that? Is it a drawback of cv2?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.arange(500*500*3)
for i in range(500*500*3):
    img[i] = 255
img = img.reshape((500, 500, 3))
cv2.imwrite("fff.jpg", img)
cv2.imshow('', img)
```

Comment: You might need to display arrays with `int8` datatype - `img.astype(np.uint8)`?

Comment: you got it. i modified the third line and added the argument "dtype=np.uint8" and it worked. it's difficult to find it. i spend hours to find it.

Comment: I can imagine this is a recurring problem, so I found the documentation and linked to it in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the `cv2` module is a thin wrapper around the C++ OpenCV package. Here's the documentation for it, and the signature doesn't change for the python wrapper functions that interface them. From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563) -

> ```
> void cv::imshow   (const String &winname,
>        InputArray     mat 
>  )
> ```
>
> Displays an image in the specified window.
>
> The function imshow displays an image in the specified window. [...]
>
> - If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
> - If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That
>     is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255].
> - If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

By default, numpy arrays are initialised to `np.int32` or `np.int64` type (it depends on your machine). If you want your arrays displayed without any change, you should ensure that you pass them as 8-bit unsigned. In your case, like this -

```
cv2.imshow('', img.astype(np.uint8))
```

Alternatively, when initialising your arrays, do so as -

```
img = np.arange(..., dtype=np.uint8)
```